# How to add the output of an object's function to an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is hard to phrase into words but I want to get the returned value of a function that is stored in an object, add that value to an array and output it. I have made this all work but it doesn't change once ran again, so say it outputs the random number of 678 it will also output that same number next time and so on. I created this cool terminal in react that gets the command of the key if it exists and outputs it in my console by returning jsx.

Here is my file structure...

[image]

Here is my react code... ( I had issues formatting, [here](https://gist.github.com/tjkSec/00f034e8b885a2cf8aaea62a96fb2363) is a better version of the code below)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import "./Main.css";
import Commands from "../Commands/Commands.js"

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {inputValue: ''}
        this.outputs = ["type 'help' for information about     plunketTheTerminal"];

        this.commands = Commands;

        this.commands.keys = Object.keys(this.commands)
    }
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if(event.key == "Enter") {
        if( this.state.inputValue != "" ) {
            if( this.commands.keys.includes(this.state.inputValue)) {
                this.outputs.unshift(this.commands[this.state.inputValue]);
            }
            else{
                this.outputs.unshift(`No command '${this.state.inputValue}' found.`)
            }
        }
        document.querySelector(".input-section").value = "";
    }
    this.forceUpdate()
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })
}
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="terminal-header"></div>
            <div className="terminal-body">
                <div className="terminal-contents-wrapper">
                    <div className="output-item-wrapper">
                        {
                            this.outputs.map((output, index) => {
                                return <h1 className="output-item" key={ index }>{output}</h1>;
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-section-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" className="input-section" onKeyPress={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        <span className="input-section-label">plunketTheTerminal@plunketTheTerminal-H170-D3H:~$</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
    };

export default Main;
```

Finally my JavaScript file for the commands... ( again better code [here](https://gist.github.com/tjkSec/a2c3d9ebb11e4795363f5fb4b159a860) )

```
const rand = () => {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1;
}

const Commands = {
    help: "plunketTheTerminal is a online terminal for fun, it contains lots     of different functions and commands. In fact you can actually SUBMIT YOUR OWN      COMMANDS at our github if you are good with computers :).",
    rand: rand(),
    "rand --info": "Will generate a random number between 1 and 1000",

}
export default Commands
```

EDIT: Trying to use either of the following returns nothing.

```
rand: () => (
    "x"
),
```

or

```
rand: () => {
    return "x"
},
```

Here is a demonstration of what is happening...

I type the command...
[image]

I get my output which is fine...
[image]

but from then on repeating that same command won't generate a new random number i will continue to repeat the first returned value.

[image]

I would really appreciate some help but please keep in mind I am still learning react and JavaScript and would love to hear any constructive feedback. I will also continue to update information if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, I was calling the function without its parentheses. I had to change the command file to the following...

```
const Commands = {
help: "plunketTheTerminal is a online terminal for fun, it contains lots of different functions and commands. In fact you can SUBMIT YOUR OWN COMMANDS at our github if you are good with computers :).",
rand: () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1;
},
//"rand --info": "Will generate a random number between 1 and 1000",

}
```

and I had to change the line

```
this.outputs.unshift(this.commands[this.state.inputValue]);
```

to

```
this.outputs.unshift(this.commands[this.state.inputValue]());
```

silly mistake, hopefully this helps someone who has a somewhat similar problem, though I think it would be unlikely.